# IE Automation using vbScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to automate one of my office's website but I am getting "The interface is unknown" error on the last line of my code.

I also tried using .Document.getElementsByName("").Item(0).Value = "02121" and .Document.getElementById("").Value = "02121", but still no luck

The inspect element of that particular field looks like:

```
<input name="npleSearchCriteria.searchByLEIdCriteria.partyId[0]._value" class="textfield"
id="npleSearchCriteria.searchByLEIdCriteria.partyId[0]._value" onkeypress="searchCriteria21();" type="text"></input>
```

My code is this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie, x

Set x = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visibke = True
WScript.Sleep 2000
ie.Navigate "http://wcvirtual.machine.test.group/CormcWeb/"

'The above link is modified since I am trying to automate one of office's websites

WScript.Sleep 2000

'Above link opens a window security dialogue box
x.sendkeys("USERNAME")
x.sendkeys("{TAB}")
x.sendkeys("PASSWORD")
x.sendkeys("{ENTER}")

WScript.Sleep 2000

ie.Document.All.Item("npleSearchCriteria.searchByLEIdCriteria.partyId[0]._value").Value = "02121"
```

Comment: That last line is all sorts of wrong. Shouldn't it be `ie.Document.GetElementByID("npleSearchCriteria.searchByLEIdCriteria.partyId[0]._value").Value = "02121"`, to be honest is `npleSearchCriteria.searchByLEIdCriteria.partyId[0]._value` a valid name for an HTML input element?

Comment: Is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63022797/692942) why have you posted another question instead of improving the first one?

Comment: That's why I wrote what I could see after using inspect element on that particular field I want to access above and I also tried getElementById. And yes it's a bit related but that code has its own errors as in this one I am opening a new tab and in that one I am using an already opened tab. Though a solution on any one of these could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by Internet Explorer security settings. You could try to uncheck the "Enable Protected Mode" setting in Security tab to see if it can work.

Besides, instead of using

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

you could use

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

and there's no need to change IE settings in this situation.

Note: `InternetExplorerMedium` requires a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

Comment: Can't change Security settings as access is restricted. And there is no reference to Microsoft Internet Controls. :(

Comment: You can find the reference in **Tools-> Reference**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTLs.png. For more information, you could also refer to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-find-reference-to-microsoft-internet-controls/e138ff0c-8046-47b1-9c0c-ac28cebe3c7a).

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` in VBScript because it only supports late binding unlike VBA.